# How can I dynamically add HTML div boxes via ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I wish to use ng-repeat tag for reading the product list in JSON.
Suppose if I have 10 products in JSON then it shall create 10 div boxes (Something similar to the e-commerce products page) 
I am unable to create these div boxes via ng-repeat. 
Can someone help me with any example ? 
I wish to display something like this .

[image]

**EDIT**

I am not concerned about data here. 
My question is that how can I add those rectangular div boxes as seen in the image attached in the question.

Comment: did you use angular.fromJson(json); before trying to use ng-repeat ?

Comment: you say you were unable to create via ng-repeat. please show your attempt

Comment: All you have to do is style the divs using css.

Answer (score 1):

Supose in the controller you set a list of items to $scope.items, and every item has a name and a code.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
     <p>{{item.name}} - {{item.code}}<p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Joaquin, 
I am not concerned about data here. 
My question is that how can I add those rectangular div boxes as seen in the image attached in the question.

Comment: Oh sorry, do you use any framework? like Bootstrap for example?

Comment: Yes, I am using bootstrap for rich CSS.

Comment: You can use [Grid Options of Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

Example:
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="item in items">...</div>
</div>